# Would this usage of FlUrl manage dns changes

Tags: .net-core, flurl

In .net core 2.1, I'm using the library Flurl to prevent the famous HttpClient socket exhaustion problem. Because I'm using legacy software, we cannot use DI injection.
So I'm doing something really simple like this:

```
var responseMessage = await url.PostAsync(content);
```

In the  documentation, it says:

> Fluent methods like this will create an HTTP client lazily, cache it, and resue it for every call to the same host:

However, I can't find any information on potential DNS changes. Since it uses caching, are DNS changes managed somehow by the library? If not, how can I track DNS changes as well as prevent the socket exhaustion problem?

Answer (score 1):

Flurl has the ability to periodically dispose/recreate underlying `HttpClient` instances via global configuration (done at app startup):

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

This is similar in intent to the [popular solution to the DNS problem](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html) that uses .NET Framework's `ServicePointManager.ConnectionLeaseTimeout`, except it works on all platforms.

An alternative introduced in .NET Core 2.1 is to use the rather poorly documented [SocketsHttpHandler.PooledConnectionLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.pooledconnectionlifetime). This is the [recommended](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224#issuecomment-394396643) solution on .NET Core, and Flurl can tap into it with a custom factory:

```
public class ConnectionLifetimeHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return new SocketsHttpHandler {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        };
    }
}
```

Then register it at startup:

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new ConnectionLifetimeHttpClientFactory());
```

Just as a warning, I haven't actually tested that, but it should work, and I would probably recommend it just slightly over the first option since it taps into more platform-native functionality and is therefore probably a little more efficient.